# Getting Facebook Notification in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I'm trying to develop an app to get my Facebook and twitter notification simultaneously. I can authenticate using Facebook SDK 4.18 and Fabric API for twitter.I can update status and tweet simultaneously. All the reference I've searched so far, some of them are not up to date.
Here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications) it is said that(regarding notification)
*

> Reading
>   You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

*

Will it not be possible to get Facebook notification?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the reason why I can't get notification. I've used Facebook SDK for making a thirdparty app. If Facebook give me permission to read the notifications, it becomes a privacy issue. So I can only post status on behalf of the app but can't get notifications.